# "SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when using DSN engine = sa.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)"

Tags: sql-server, fastapi, pypyodbc

Having issues connecting to my sql-server using pyodbc after several checks.

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pyodbc

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"mssql+pyodbc://user_one:secret@DESKTOP-6T5DDMB\mypassword/Billy+Driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0',echo=True"

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Comment: So what kind of error are you getting? According to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#connecting-to-pyodbc you should have a `?` before the driver information; I'm also not sure what `mypassword` is doing there, since that's the `secret` part in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

So after a thorough research from stackoverflow i discovered i was missing some syntax from my code using a wrong connecting string.

wrong: `f"mssql+pyodbc://user_one:secret@DESKTOP-6T5DDMB\mypassword/Billy+Driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0',echo=True"`

Right:

import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as

`mssql+pyodbc://DESKTOP-6T5DDMB\mypassword/Billy?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0`

engine = sa.create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

And this is applicable when using Windows Authentication.